# Get first value that is not false from json mixed types

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This seems like it should be straight forward but I'm not sure why `Powershell` is having trouble.

I'm getting data from `Node.js` converting it to `JSON` and then I want to get the first object which is not `false`.

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json").Content |
    ConvertFrom-Json | ? { $_.lts -ne 'False' }
```

I also tried but it didn't work either:

```
| ? { -not (-not $_.lts) }
```

I know the above doesn't actually get me the first value. I haven't found that solution yet. But help with that would be nice too!

The data set is something like this:

```
[
    {"lts": false},
    {"lts": 'Carbon'}
]
```

[You can see the complete data set here.](https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json)

**Update**

When I set the `JSON` value to a variable it works. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json' `
    |% Content `
    | ConvertFrom-Json `
    |% { $_ } `
    |? lts -ne $False `
    ;
```

The `ConvertFrom-Json` converts the JSON array into `Object[]` which has to be exploded to be processed record-by-record. The `ForEach-Object` after `ConvertFrom-Json` splits them up nicely.